# How to implement to limit upload file size when using boost asio

Tags: c++, http, boost, asio

when I use boost asio to implement a http server,I have encountered a question that is,I want to limit a upload file size,when the program check the file'size is more than size that I give,then write response to browser and close the socket immediately,but this processing will make browser `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`,So,how to return reseponse `413 state` and close the socket connection when clients still have data to send,or If my way would be wrong,how to implement that?

Comment: Would you consider using Boost Beast?  It has this feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556690/how-do-i-avoid-body-limit-error-in-boosts-beast-and-correctly-handle-large-mess

Comment: @JohnZwinck  I just want to implement it  by asio,how to limit file size using correctly method.

Comment: Then perhaps you should look at how Beast does it, probably you can follow their example.